# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 suspend issues

Tags: suspend, 16.04, mate

My system (HP Pavilion 15-ac630tx) hangs every time when I suspend. The screen is blank but the CPU fan is still spinning. None of the suggestions I have read (like switching to a terminal, various scripts, disabling various drivers, the SysRq key) have any effect. Before I upgraded from an earlier version the same problem occurred, but was intermittent.

```
lsb_release -a:
steve@StevePC:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenia

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

I am newbie Linux user from Windows 10, and I must admit it's a shock to the system. So far the transition has been extremely unpleasant, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

This is most likely due to a bug in the 4.4.0 kernel. The problem can be solved when you install the new kernel 4.4.8.

You can find instruction to do it here: http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Glad that worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

most probably its driver issue for intel graphics card. Open "software and updates" from dash, go to "additional drivers" tab, and check if any proprietory drivers are pending for install. 
If drivers are there, follow https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend to troubleshoot suspend (kernel testing facility). It can clearly point out the stage where suspend fails. hope it works.